# what the grammar ことぐらい mean

Tags: particle-くらい

I bump up in in sentence on manga

```
僕とじゃ釣り合わないことぐらい
```

I guess the translation is that I am not fit for

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34132/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 僕とじゃ釣り合わない**ことぐらい**

The sentence is cut off. It would depend on the context, but the unsaid, implied half of it should probably be something like わかってる。 or 知ってる。

The こと is a nominalizer. It functions like "that..." in English, as in:

> 「[sentence]+ **こと**を知っている。/ **こと**がわかっている。」
>   = "I know **that** +[sentence]."

くらい/ぐらい is a belittling suffix. (The particle くらい/ぐらい replaces the case particle を/が.) It can express [how minimal, trivial, slight, weak, easy, etc. something is](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34132/9831). For more on the usage of くらい/ぐらい and examples please refer to:

- [Understanding くらい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34126/9831)
- [The difference between くらい and ほど in hyperbole](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2392/9831)
- [Meaning of ぐらいじゃ足りない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33995/9831)

So your sentence means something like:

> 僕とじゃ釣り合わないことぐらい（わかってる。/知ってる。）
>   "I know very well that I'm not enough for (you/her/someone)."
>   "I'm well/fully aware that I'm not good enough for (you/her/someone)."

with a nuance that the fact is so obvious, easy to know, etc.

Comment: Oh that's make sense. I undrstood the context of ぐらい from the resources, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

こと　Things

話したいことがある。　There's something I want to talk about.
頼みたいことがある。　There's something I want to you to do me a favor.

ぐらい　OR　くらい　As if
英語くらい話せて当然だ。　You should speak English. (disregard)
それぐらいしか思いつきません。　I can only recall about that much.(disregard)

僕とじゃ釣り合わないことぐらい（すぐ分かる）　It is too obvious  that I am not fit for you.